# What do pipes between brackets mean in a regex?

Tags: regex, vim

Reading this [vim plugin](https://github.com/vim-scripts/Twee-Integration-for-Vim/blob/master/syntax/twee.vim) I see this line:

```
syntax match tweeDelimiter "[<<|>>|\]\]|\[\[]"
```

To me, that regex doesn't make much sense when it's surrounded by `[]`.  According to [this](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html), "POSIX bracket expressions match one character out of a set of characters".

So isn't this matching < or > or [ or ]?  I know from context that it's trying to match << or >> or [[ or ]].

Comment: You're right, the regex doesn't make much sense. Shorthand you can use `[][<>|]` or `[\][<>|]` (in languages that accept empty sets like JavaScript) which produces the same result. This basically matches the characters `<|>[]`. I believe the intent was a regex in this shape: `(<<|>>|\]\]|\[\[)` which matches either `<<`, `>>`, `]]`, or `[[`

Comment: Imo this is equivalent to `[<>|\[\]]`

Comment: I'm not sure about how this plugin in particular utilizes Regular Expressions but in PCRE both opening / closing brackets may denote a delimiter which makes sense in this context too.

Comment: @revo in this context, I don't think it makes sense.  The language doesn't have [<< as syntax.

Comment: If we are talking about *delimiters*, it shouldn't have support such a syntax truly: *It is also possible to use bracket style delimiters where the opening and closing brackets are the starting and ending delimiter, respectively. (), {}, [] and <> are all valid bracket style delimiter pairs.*

Answer (score 1):

That indeed looks like a bug in the plugin. If it wants to match *pairs* of those characters, it has to use plain *regexp branches* (`\|`), not a *collection*:

```
<<\|>>\|\]\]\|\[\[
```

If there were additional stuff to match, above would have to be enclosed in `\%(...\)` to group it. However, using `[...]` will match *any* of the contained characters; Vim just ignores the duplicate ones. As others have commented already, such could be written in shorter form, for example `[][<>|]`.

---

So, if the plugin indeed mistakenly matches stuff like `<>` and `<[` instead of just `<<` and `[[`, please inform its author about the bug.